# search and replace a string after a match

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a file that contains :

```
String url = "https://url_address/v2.0/vpc/peerings?name=change_variable"
```

I try to change the string change_variable with something else like

```
String url = "https://url_adress/v2.0/vpc/peerings?name=florian-testpeering-5"
```

But when I use :

```
sed 's/"https:\/\/url_adress\/v2.0\/vpc\/peerings?name/"https:\/\/url_adress\/v2.0\/vpc\/peerings?name=florian-testpeering-5"/'g
```

I Obtain :

```
String url = "https://url_adress/v2.0/vpc/peerings?name=florian-testpeering-5"=change_url"
```

What I did wrong ?

Edit :

To be more precise, I need to change the change_variable inside with a $peering who I declare before in my script.

Comment: Where is the 'change_variable"' in the original text of the sed command?

Comment: sed doesn't understand literal strings and is limited to characters that don't match whatever delimiter you use so you shouldn't try to use sed for something like this, you should use awk instead since it does have literal string functionality. Are you trying to replace the string `https://url_address/v2.0/vpc/peerings?name=change_variable` or whatever string happens to be in quotes after `String url = ` or a combination of both or something else?

Comment: So, first I try to change, change_variable Wich is a variable that I had before which is only in this string after String Url =. So don't know, I wanted to search with sed the littéral string and change it with another with the change variable

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have forward slashes in the url, means that is better to use another character for the sed separator and so:

```
sed 's@String url = "https://url_address/v2.0/vpc/peerings?name=change_variable"@String url = "https://url_address/v2.0/vpc/peerings?name=florian-testpeering-5"@g'
```

The normal / has been changed for @, allowing for easier reading and processing of the url.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
awk 'index($0,"https://url_address/v2.0/vpc/peerings?name=change_variable") { sub(/change_variable/,"florian-testpeering-5") } 1' file
String url = "https://url_address/v2.0/vpc/peerings?name=florian-testpeering-5"
```

Comment: Could work if my files contains only one string, but that contain other informations so can't use $0 if i'm not wrong.

Comment: It should work fine with more text in your input but until you provide sample input/output in your question that looks like your real data we can't test it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your edit, and you are saying you have your string in a variable at the beginning of your script, similar to:

```
var='String url = "https://url_address/v2.0/vpc/peerings?name=change_variable"'
```

and you need to change the contents of the string replacing from `name=...` to the end with a new value, you can simply use bash *parameter expansion with substring replacement*, e.g.

```
var="${var/name=*/name=florian-testpeering-5\"}"
```

Now the variable `var` will contain:

```
String url = "https://url_address/v2.0/vpc/peerings?name=florian-testpeering-5"
```

You can do the same thing if the string you want to replace with is also stored in another variable, such as `repl="lorian-testpeering-5"`, in that case your substring replacement would be:

```
var="${var/name=*/name=${repl}\"}"
```

(same result in `var`)

Comment: I try to remplace in a file the change_variable that I have in a variable define at the start but this variable will change so I need to search for this line which contain : String url = "https://url_address/v2.0/vpc/peerings?name=change_variable

Comment: You can always "*search"* with `grep "name=${repl}\$" file` (note you have the escape the `'$'` representing the REGEX end-of-line with `'\'` since you must *double-quote* the `grep` expression to allow variable expansion to take place.)

Comment: What did return that grep ? beceause when I did that, it returned me anything. I have my string in a file : String url = "https://url_address/v2.0/vpc/peerings?name=change_variable" and I have a var="new_changevariable" 
I Need to change "change_variable" by $var, but the next time I will change, it will be $var=$var2